# Width 100%: Aspect ratio of image

Tags: images, css

If I add an image to a post, WordPress hardcodes `width` and `height` attributes to the `img` tag.

I added `max-width:100%` to my CSS, but of course, if my browser window gets smaller, the resized image gets stretched in height.

What can I do about it?

Is there a way to:

**A**: Solve it with CSS (I would prefer that)?
**B**: Forbid WP to hardcode width and height?
or
**C**: Is there a common way of dealing with image widths, I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A** + **C**:

```
img.resize-proportionally {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

As an aside, for the above to work, you shouldn't attempt **B**.
Having `width` and `height` attributes in the `img` tag is good.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, I should have tried this. I just thought, it wouldn't work, because height="XXX" would be "stronger".